# ASP.NET Entity Framework Where Date Contains

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, date

I am trying to write a WHERE clause for Entity Framework where Date contains a string from the input text, the input text could be mm or mm/dd or mm/dd/yyyy so I am trying write my WHere clause like so:

```
query.Where(p => (p.AccountingDate.Value.Month.ToString() + "/" + p.AccountingDate.Value.Day.ToString() + "/" + p.AccountingDate.Value.Year.ToString).Contains(gsStr))
```

but I get this error:

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'
```

What is the best way to do this? I would really really love to use Contains instead of ==

Please Help!

Comment: Why do you want to use `Contains` on a date?

Comment: You're missing `()` after the last `ToString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'

You forgot to invoke the `.ToString` method:

```
"/" + p.AccountingDate.Value.Year.ToString
```

should be:

```
"/" + p.AccountingDate.Value.Year.ToString()
```

The former resolves to the method itself (or "method group"), the latter resolves to the result of the method (which is a string).